# background color padding and margin

Tags: css, html

I want to color the background of both H1 and H2 same color. i am getting a white space between H1 and H2. How can do it?

```css
    h1{
        border: 2px solid springgreen;   
        background-color: rgb(168,213,255); }

    #top{
        border: 2px solid  red;
        text-align: left; }

    #sub{
        border: 2px solid  orange;
        background-color: rgb(168,213,255) }
```

```html
<div id="top">
            <h1> First Heading</h1>
            <h2 id="sub">Sub Heading</h2>
     </div>
```

Comment: Margin will not get coloured u need to remove margin if anything there in h tag

Comment: paragraph and heading tag default margin every time. For removing space between heading tag you need to give margin zero for both h1 and h2.

Comment: Position:relative

Answer (score 0):

If you require references for html and css, I would refer http://htmlreference.io and http://cssreference.io as sources for you.

As for the answer to your question:

There will be margin space issue between both h tags

```
  h1,h2{margin:0;background-color:red;}
   .top{position:relative;top:200px}
```

This will fix your issue.

I hope this would be useful for beginners. Thank you and check out http://htmlreference.io and http://cssreference.io for more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the margins between the elements:

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 { 
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Browsers have defaults that you have to take into account:

[Browser Default Values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO since its code only answer.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users –